# ASP.net nuget AJAX toolkit auto complete page method

Tags: asp.net, ajax, nuget

Installed nuget AJAX toolkit and drop auto complete extender in TextBox1 but TextBox smart tag menu not showing Add AutoCompleteExtender page method option.

I can type AutoCompleteExtender page method manually in code behind and its works fine but my question is how to add automatically like click on smart tag option?

[VS 2015 Community TextBox Smart tag screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdBVo.png)

Comment: Restarting visual studio generally solves these type of issues for me.

Comment: @Vicky_Thinking thanks i already done that but not showing.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET AJAX features require that the System.Web.Extensions assembly be installed in the global assembly cache (GAC) of the server where the Web application is hosted. If the assembly is available, your application and any associated controls in the App_Code folder or in an assembly the Bin folder can use AJAX features.

Use the following code to determine whether ASP.NET AJAX is installed in the global assembly cache.
C#

```
Private static readonly object ReflectionLock = new object();
Lock (ReflectionLock)
{
    Type scriptManagerType =
       Type.GetType(
       "System.Web.UI.ScriptManager, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35",
       false);
    if (scriptManagerType != null)
        // ASP.NET AJAX is installed.
    else
        // ASP.NET AJAX is not installed.
}
```

Even if ASP.NET AJAX functionality is enabled for a Web application, you might have to check whether AJAX functionality is enabled for an individual page.

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page)
if (sm == null)
{
    // ASP.NET AJAX functionality is not enabled for the page.
}
else
{
    // AJAX functionality is enabled for the page.
}
```